# Where to store a real time strategy data?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a basic RTS, but I have no idea where can I store data, for example units, buildings, etc. I'd like to avoid making a hundreds of .txt files (or one, very big .txt file). Well, I could just write a header with a class of every single object, but wouldn't it be too much? I mean, if I make about 20 units (in total, of course) with similar stats (range, attack value, health, etc.) and only with different special abilities, I think it is quite strange to set everything in 20 constructors, doesn't it?

Another problem is with storing a map. I think I'll try the .txt solution here, but I'm probably going to write some kind of map editor in WinAPI or sth like that, setting the map in the .txt file would be a torment. So I know how to represent tiles (I want the map to be a tiled one, it will be much easier to implement, I suppose), but what if there is a unit that takes more than only one tile, how can I deal with this?

Comment: Too much questions, too much possible valid answers. You probably need to read more tuts/articles about RTS, don't start if you don't know where to start or you will just lose your time. For data you can start with xml.

Comment: My vote's for XML too. And for units that span more than one tile, don't bother recording them all. Just record the central position and orientation, and determine what tiles it fills when you load up the map again. Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow - I think you'll need to be a little further in the development cycle before posing a question here.

Comment: Or try in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for replies, I'll switch to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ then. I like the idea of XML, I've never used it before, but it seems like a good opportunity to finally check what is it all about :)

Comment: u can also use JsonObject it's pretty just the same as xml but smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Txt and XML are not great solutions, and also writing and reading from disk isn't the cheapest operation you can do in real time. The way to do this in Unity is through Serialization, basically you write a class that allow you to store data without instantiating a GameObject for it, and whenever you'd like to, you can save or load it at runtime. There is also a great tutorial about data persistence on Unity Tutorials page. ([Link Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data))

Comment: Oh, this one looks interesting! Seems like a good option for loading and saving maps. Really like this one, thanks! It even allows me to make in-game map editor (of course a simple one, nothing advanced).

Comment: I almost forgot! There is [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBA1QCoEAX4&t=1724s) great video about all the things you can do with serialized objects, I'd strongly suggest you to give it a look! Once you have your serialized data, Unity has countless tools to make you build your own editor tools, basic or advanced it's just up to you! Good luck! (and don't forget to mark the right answer as solution!)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the [Easy Save](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/768) plugin. I'd set it up so it only saves to disk every few seconds, not a constant stream.  Also, with Easy Save you can save just bits and pieces to a larger save file rather than saving everything with each pass.  If the game crashes, you might lose a couple seconds of progress, but that should be an acceptable loss in the case of a crash or quit.